# Считать двумерный вещественный массив Golang с файла

Tags: массивы, файлы, golang, матрицы

Хочу считать двумерный вещественный массив чисел. Дошел до момента, где уменя в строке data хранится содержимое файла, однако я не знаю как можно сделать на основе этого двумерный массив вещественных чисел:
Вот код:

```
package main

import (
"fmt"
//"gonum.org/v1/gonum/mat"
"io"
"os"
"strconv"
)


func main() {
file, err := os.Open("matrix")
if err != nil{
    fmt.Println(err)
    os.Exit(1)
}
defer file.Close()

data := make([]byte, 64)

for{
    n, err := file.Read(data)
    if err == io.EOF{
        break
        }
    fmt.Print(string(data[:n]))
    }
}
```

Содержимое файла matrix:

```
5.482 0.358 0.237 0.409 0.416
0.580 4.953 0.467 0.028 0.464
0.319 0.372 8.935 0.520 0.979
0.043 0.459 0.319 4.778 0.126
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так:

```golang
r := strings.NewReader(input)
s := bufio.NewScanner(r)

var matrix [][]float64
for s.Scan() {
    records := strings.Fields(s.Text())
    line := make([]float64, len(records))
    matrix = append(matrix, line)
    for i := range records {
        line[i], err = strconv.ParseFloat(records[i], 64)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
if err = s.Err(); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/a1ykU4udBTe.